# Media player and surfaceview (Decoder error -2)

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I am developing a media player application in android using mediaplayer and surfaceview as display.

when i run this project in **real device** it play the video **without any problem**.

but when i run this project in **emulator** it gets **"Decoder failed -2"** error why ?

Comment: are the real device and the emulator on same Android version?

Comment: yes both are android 4.4